# Using modeled surfaces together to make predictions?

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics, rasterstats

My question is about stacking multiple rasters of predicted surfaces, that have some of the same predictors.

For example,  if I make a predicted surface using all the terrain attributes as predictors, and then add that interpolated surface to a new stack with the original predictors (eg slope, aspect, TPI, and the new surface) will this violate any modeling principles? Is it commonly done?

It seems problematic because I have the original predictors in the stack, and then the new interpolated surface based on those predictors in the stack too. It is like a geospatial double jeopardy.

Comment: You could ask this question in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing linear modelling (you don't say what your model is, but this applies fairly widely) then no, you can't do this, it doesn't help.

You can't add collinear terms to a model. In other words, you can do this:

```
y ~ x1 + x2
```

but not:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + 3*x1
```

and expect to get a term for `x1` and `3*x1`. (You can try this in R but you have to wrap the last term in `I()`, ie `y~x1+x2+I(3*x1)`, and you get an NA for the last term).

In general you can't have terms that are linear combinations of each other on the RHS of a model. So anything like:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + (3*x1+2*x2)
```

won't work.

The predictions of a fitted linear model are sums of a linear combination of the explanatory variables, so trying to put both the original variables and predictions on the RHS of any model will create a singularity and the model won't work.

This can be a problem when what you thought was independent data is actually near-linear combinations of other explanatory variables - look for "Multicollinearity" in a stats reference.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was getting at. It was using a predicted surface to make a prediction about a another surface (a forth surface in your example).   `d = data.frame(y=runif(10),x1=runif(10),x2=runif(10))
m = lm(y~x1+x2, data=d)
d$p = predict(m)
d$z<-runif(10)
m1<-lm(z~p+x1+x2, data=d)`

Comment: Okay try again. What you are doing is creating multicollinearlity, which makes the model unsolvable.

Comment: Thanks!  What if the technique is non parametric? Eg a random forest?